# Links are missing on TFS 2015 Update 3

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I've just updated to TFS 2015 Update 3, and now I only have these links under every project:

**"HOME - CODE - WORK - TEST"**

Previously, I had:

**"HOME - CODE - WORK - BUILD - TEST - RELEASE".**

Does anybody know how i get them back?

Can I reapply an update again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem!

Somehow the collection database (I only have one) got corrupted while installing Update 3.

**Solution:**

1. Stopped the collection
2. Detached collection and configuration database
3. Uninstalled Update 3
4. Restored Configuration and Collection database to the point just before installing Update 3
5. Installed Update 3 again
6. Done! Everything works now!